# ExpressJs execute a callback after sending a response for every route

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, express, callback

The scenario is to save the data in cache. We have numerous express routes written with complicated logic.

I have to find a way to save the response data in cache. I cannot go to each and every route and check whether this needs to be saved and save the data before sending the response. (If no other go, then this may be the way)

I have tried the following approaches.

1. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_1 - using **'close'** or **'finish'**, which fires after sending the response would do the trick. But there is no way I could get the response data in these events.
2. Also my node version is **v0.10.31**
3. Thought of using [app.all('*', callback)](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.all), but i am not sure how to catch the response data for cacheing.
4. Finally i thought of adding a second callback for routing, **app.VERB(path, [callback...], callback)**, but upon returning the response in first callback, second callback is never called.

Hoping there is a solution for this, and I am stuck in this for more than a week.

The reason why adding logic into each and every routes is a tedious job is that, I need to add a configuration entry specifying which route needs to be cached with an expiry time.

Response needs to be cached in **redis server**. A cache key will be generated based on the route data and query strings. All those complete user specific information will be saved in a key.

So when the user hits the same route the key will be generated to check if it already exists using ***app.use*** and the data will be served without precedding to the successive middlewares.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is this response data that is supposed to be cached the same for all users, or are sessions somehow involved? How about an `app.use` that checks the url and outputs the appropriate headers to cache the content. And by "cache" do you mean just save data in express, or actual browser caching or what ?

Comment: @adeneo Response needs to be cached in **redis server**. A cache key will be generated based on the route data and query strings. All those complete user specific information will be saved in a key. So when the user hits the same route the key will be generated to check if it already exists using **_app.use_** and the data will be served without precedding to the successive middlewares.

Comment: Why don't you just add your caching logic in your routes right after sending the response? You can execute code after sending the response.

Comment: @GeorgeEracleous Thanks for your response. I am fully aware that I can either cache before or after sending the response. As there are nearly 45 routes configured, i dont want to change the callback code in each and every route to cache the response before/after sending it. I just wanted to know if anyone tried achieving this without modifying the callback. Hope i am clear.

Answer (score 0):

Define a callback middleware as,

```
var storeResponseMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("storing data in redis....")
  ..........more stuff
}
```

Add it to expressJs app as,

```
app.use(logicRoute)
app.use(storeResponseMiddleware)
```

Now, for all the responses `storeResponseMiddleware` will be called. you must call `next()` inside the route handlers.